# (quasi)metric on Riemannian manifolds via Brownian Motion?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, brownian-motion, information-geometry

Given points $a$ and $b$ on a Riemannian manifold $M$, I would like a (quasi)metric that corresponds to some property of Brownian Motion from $a$ to $b$ (or rather, to $\epsilon$-ball $B = \{ x : |x - b| < \epsilon\}$).

Possible ways of defining such a (quasi)metric:

- Let $d(a,b) = g(\epsilon) h_M(T_{aB})$, where $T_{aB}$ is the average commute time from $a$ to $B$, and $g(\epsilon)$ is the normalization function.
- Let $d(a,b)$ be a function of the probability of reaching $B$ before time $T$. (suggested by [Arthur B](https://mathoverflow.net/users/8737/arthur-b))

In either case, is $d$ a metric?  Is it very different from geodesic distance?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will not be a metric if the space has a dimension > 1, because the Brownian commute times grow proportionally to r^d. This means you'll violate the triangle inequality: for example, if A, C, B are in a line on the plane and d(A, C) = d(C, B) = 1 and our scaling factor is conveniently 1, you'd have d(A, B) = 4 > 2 = d(A, C) + d(C, B).

Comment: Can we instead use a function of the average commute time?

Comment: The d-th root would make it possible to satisfy the triangle inequality, and should technically be a metric, but wouldn't seem to make practical sense.

Comment: A metric based on the probability of reaching an epsilon ball in time t < T perhaps.

Comment: Thanks Aaron and Arthur!  I have edited the question to incorporate your suggestions.